# How do I know/get notified that my activity (android) has ended?

Tags: java, android

I would like to know when an activity I have started ends. How can I do that when the code related to the activity is:

```java
intent_record_video = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
intent_record_video.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 5);
startActivityForResult(intent_record_video, VIDEO_CAPTURE);
```

The code above is all the code related to the activity of recording a video. I want to know when it has ended/ be notified when it ends. How do I do that?

Comment: Override `onActivityResult`.

Comment: [Here's how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android)

Comment: thank you for these responses, but the problem is that this solution is for custom coded activities. I use an in-built camera activity for recording a video (MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE). Hence, I don't think this will be of much help.

Comment: If you're starting the activity for a result, you'll know when it's done when you get `onActivityResult`, as the linked question describes.